# MySQL workbench - Linking tables

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to link 'Klant' & 'Winkel' by making a third table named 'Klantwinkel'.
This is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE Klant (
    klantnummer int(10) not NULL,
    voornaam varchar(10) not NULL,
    achternaam varchar(10) not NULL,
    adres varchar(20) not NULL,
    e_mail varchar(40) not NULL,
    primary key(klantnummer)
);

CREATE TABLE Winkel (
    winkelnummer int(4) not NULL,
    winkelnaam varchar(20) not NULL,
    winkeladres varchar(30) not NULL,
    primary key(winkelnummer)
);

CREATE TABLE Klantwinkel (
    klantnummer int(10) not NULL,
    winkelnummer int(4) not NULL,
    primary key(klantnummer, winkelnummer),
    foreign key(klantnummer) references klant(klantnummer),
    foreign key(winkelnummer) references Winkel(winkelnummer)
);
```

I'm receiving an error code 1005. Can anyone help me?
Happy New Year!

EDIT: I think I had an invisible capital error. I rewrote the first letter of every word and it suddenly works now!

```
 foreign key(klantnummer) references klant(klantnummer),
```

'klant' didn't have the capital K.

Comment: It should work **[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26c5b/1/0)**

Comment: It's not working in workbench..

Comment: I get error code 1005. Can't create table 'xxx.Klantwinkel' (errno:150).. Weird part is, I have more tables like these, and there it works..

Comment: You must be doing something different than you posted here, because it works when we copy it. Maybe you have a typo in the real code. Make sure you create `Kaltwinkel` **after** you create the frist two tables.

Comment: I think I had an invisible capital error.. I rewrote the firstletter of every word and it suddenly works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table names are case sensitive in UNIX but not in Windows environment.
By default in MySQL configurable files the value is `lower_case_table_names=0`.
0 represents case sensitive, which happens in your case and gave the error.
As per documentation-

```
System Variable Name    lower_case_table_names
Variable Scope  Global
Dynamic Variable    No
Permitted Values    Type    integer
Default 0
Min Value   0
Max Value   2

If set to 0, table names are stored as specified and comparisons are case sensitive. If set to 1, table names are stored in lowercase on disk and comparisons are not case sensitive. If set to 2, table names are stored as given but compared in lowercase. This option also applies to database names and table aliases. For additional information, see Section 9.2.2, “Identifier Case Sensitivity”.

On Windows the default value is 1. On OS X, the default value is 2.

You should not set lower_case_table_names to 0 if you are running MySQL on a system where the data directory resides on a case-insensitive file system (such as on Windows or OS X). It is an unsupported combination that could result in a hang condition when running an INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM tbl_name operation with the wrong tbl_name letter case. With MyISAM, accessing table names using different letter cases could cause index corruption.
```

Source- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html

Comment: you can check mysql system variable with - show variables;